# JavaScript and CORS from local machine on Comcast

Tags: javascript, salesforce, cors, local

I'm processing data locally and issuing GET commands to force.com.  Since that's a Salesforce domain their security is super tight (a good thing), I need to add the origin URL to the CORS whitelist.

I'm running the scripts locally on my home machine and my internet provider is Comcast with a dynamic IP.

So, what do I whitelist?  All of Comcast?  Is there a way I can be more granular than that?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to get a (cheap) domain name and point it at your IP address.  That way, the CORS whitelist will key off that domain name.

Comment: Thanks - How would I manually set the origin to be my domain so I don't show as Comcast?

Comment: I'm assuming you are accessing your internal site via a web browser, and that the GET call to salesforce is happening via AJAX.  If so, whatever the hostname is you are using to access your internal site is used as the `ORIGIN` in CORS.